# How to open a alert box within anchor tag <a href>?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open a alert box when a certain link is clicked. How to do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "pop up"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript popup alert on link click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813674/javascript-popup-alert-on-link-click)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can also use the following codes:

```
<a href="#" id="link">Link</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on("click","#link",function(){
 alert("I am a pop up ! ");
});
```

OR:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('I am a popup!');">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

Without using a JS file (purely as an alternative to answers already posted):

```
<a href="http://example.com" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Link Text</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(); return false;">
```

The `return false;` will stop the web page being loaded after clicking.

JavaScript code:

```
function myFunction() {
   alert("I am a pop up ! ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code might help:-

```
<a id="anchor">i am the anchor</a>
<div id="popup">this is a popup</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#popup').hide();
        $('#anchor').click(function(){
            $('#popup').show();
        })
    });
</script>
```