# Show prompt after user clicks on a link that navigates to a new site

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, prompt

I'm trying to create a function that will show a prompt or modal when a user clicks on a link that will navigate the user to another site. For instance, the site I'm working on has links that go to outside medical sites.

I've tried several functions that show a prompt before the website closes, but not before the site navigates to a new site.

```
<a v-bind:href="item.url" target="_blank" class="evidence-links" rel="external nofollow">${item.title}</a>
```

```
function goodbye(e) {
    if(!e) e = window
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = 'You sure you want to leave?';

       if (e.stopPropagation) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
       }
}
window.onbeforeunload=goodbye;
```

I wonder if target="_blank" prevents it from working? I'd like to keep that part, though.

Comment: Where is `target="_blank"` in your code?

Comment: @JackBashford just added it

Comment: `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', goodbye)` and remove your `if(!e)` check

Comment: I figured it out from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813674/javascript-popup-alert-on-link-click